# How do I split a string of words into seperate string variables in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I'm using fgets() to pull the first line of a txt file that I made with another program and save it as a string. The problem is that I'd like to assign each word as a different variable.

Here is the first line of my txt file:

```
1435055708,10.9336,8.2295,11.8359,8.2734,10.8750,8.2148,14.6670,12.9922,
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$outputFile = fopen("output.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open data log file!");
$firstLine = fgets($outputFile);
echo $firstLine;
?>
```

This just stores the line as the string $firstLine.

I'm trying to split this line into 9 variables

```
Timestamp = 1435055708
Channel 0 = 10.9336
Channel 1 = 8.2295
...and so on
```

Comment: `explode(',',$your_string)`.This'll create an array

Comment: A simple [explode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php) +  [list](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.list.php) should get you what you want `list($timestamp, $channel0, ....) = explode(',', $firstLine);`

Comment: I think you've misplaced the parameters within function @cyrbil  `explode($firstLine, ',');`

Comment: Yep you are right :) edited ty. PHP is so inconsistant with parameters orders ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the data structure is always the same in your file you can go like this:

```
$parts = explode(',', $firstLine);
list($timestamp, $channel0, $channel1, ...) = $parts;
```

The first line will slice your string into an array (every comma separated value will become a new value in an array).

The second line will take the array values and assign them to your desired variables.

Of course all of this can be joined into a single line:

```
list($timestamp, $channel0, $channel1, ...) = explode(',', fgets($outputFile));
```

Answer (score 1):

@MaGnetas solution is correct just an explanation
explode will break the firstline by delimiter ',' and return an zero indexed array which you can use as it is or create a list

```
$arr = explode(',',$firstLine);
```